# VSTO: include database in Excel file or VSTO Add-In

Tags: database, excel, vsto, integrate

Is it somehow possible to integrate a database in an VSTO project?
Due to the amount of data I have to switch to an proper database. The only issue is that the users got too accustomed on the Excel interface, I'm not that optimistic to make them accept a new interface.
In order avoid to manage two files I would like to have the database included/hidden in a Excel file.

Comment: So each user would have a unique copy of the database? Or do you mean one centralized db?

Comment: Wow that was quick. There would be a working copy per job. After the job is finished the data in the database will be copied in a centralised database and the working copy will be archived as the other job files.

Comment: SQL Server CE 3.5 or SQL Server LocalDB would work.

Comment: How can I hide them in a Excel file?

Comment: Are you using C# or VB.NET for the VSTO Add-In?

Comment: As you like, I could either of them

Answer (score 0):

VSTO has [custom parts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608618.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) but it only supports XML. If you can store the database as XML, maybe by creating an object model and persisting that, you can use custom parts.

If you need to store a literal database file, you might need to do it somewhere on the filesystem outside a workbook. If you do that, you can access it the same way any other program would.

Comment: That could be a solution a roughly familiar with the concept of the XML schema of the new office file format. I modified once some part in a `.xlsx` in order to have document specific ribbon. The only question is how to create an XML database. The data can be extracted later on when the file is returned to the specialist who feeds the main database.
Any idea how to get the XML database realized?

Comment: It wouldn't be a database exactly, just serialized objects. You probably have to write the logic that reads from the DB and creates objects, and back again if you want that, or there might be libraries that do that automatically, I'm not sure. See [Serializable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973893.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Server CE in your VSTO Add-In.

If you want to install it with the Add-In, you'll need to include the following dll files to the root directory of your project. This example is for SQL Server CE 3.5.

- sqlceca35.dll
- sqlcecompact35.dll
- sqlceer35EN.dll
- sqlceme35.dll
- sqlceoledb35.dll
- sqlceqp35.dll
- sqlcese35.dll

[image]

Then update the properties for of the dlls as well as the database file to the following.

[image]

References:

[MSDN Deploying SQL Server CE with a Clickonce application](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/5042b5ba-26ca-4b36-b727-9ee59410925b/deploying-sql-server-ce-with-a-clickonce-application?forum=winformssetup)

[Merge Replication with SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 and SQL Server 2014 and 2012](http://erikej.blogspot.com.au/2014/04/merge-replication-with-sql-server.html)

[Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 Service Pack 2 for Windows Desktop](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=5783)

[SQL Server Compact Toolbox for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.SQLServerCompactSQLiteToolbox)

Comment: thank you, that looks like a decent and small database but it would still require a separated database file, wouldn't it?.  
That would be much of deal if you integrate it in an Add-In but what about doing the same for Excel VSTO Workbook project? Any chance to integrate it, so that the user doesn't know that there is a integrated database? The less the user knows the better.

Comment: I don't think you would be able to integrate it into a workbook, but you can copy the database to a folder on their c drive

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: To be honest I have not checked yet as my creative spare time is still very limited